# How To Get Multiple Counts In One Query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a `BlogPost` model, and two of its attributes are `draft: Boolean` and `user: String`.

Is it possible to get the following counts in one query using mongo's aggregation framework with Mongoose?

```
BlogPost.count({ user: userID }, function(err, response() {});
BlogPost.count({ user: userID, draft: true }, function(err, response() {});
```

Comment: Yes you can use $cond to conditionally sum up the other draft_count field if draft is true

Answer (score 4):

The [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator is a ternary operator that evaluates a conditional expression to `true/false` and returns either the second or third arguments respectively depending on the evaluation. Your field in this case is either boolean `true/false`, so there is no need to test with another operator. You implement this inside the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/):

```
BlogPost.aggregate(
    [
        { "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "total_count": { "$sum": 1 },
            "draft_count": { "$sum": { "$cond": [ "$draft", 1, 0 ] } }
        }
    ],
    function(err,results) {

    }
);
```

Passing in `null` to the `_id` value of group means that you are not "grouping" on any specific document key but are grouping **all** of the documents in the collection.

Comment: Thanks Neil, going to try this out later today!

Comment: Neil, I just tried this out, and it works for all documents.  However, in the original question I ask how to specify two conditions: draft Boolean and also user: String.  How can I put the user condition in there along with the draft condition to perform this operation on only  BlogPosts of a specific user?

Comment: @ac360 Use the `$match` pipeline stage at the head of the aggregation pipeline. It takes all the same query options as `.find()`

Answer (score 1):

this is an aggregation query when we have to count more than ten tables data in one query we use it

```
   const res= await taskModel.aggregate([
            {
                $facet:
                {
                    "count1": [
                        {
                            $match:
                                { user_id: ObjectId(data.user_id) }
                        }, { $count: "mycount" }]
                    ,
                    "count2":
                        [{
                            $match:
                            {
                                $and:
                                    [{ user_id: ObjectId(data.user_id) }, { task_status: 2 }]
                            }
                        },
                        { $count: "mycount" }]
                }
            }])
```